# Try run Hive and have Error:“java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 3.0.0-alpha1”

Tags: hadoop

I have a version of Hadoop on Ubuntu 16.10

```
Hadoop 3.0.0-alpha1
Source code repository https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r a990d2ebcd6de5d7dc2d3684930759b0f0ea4dc3
Compiled by andrew on 2016-08-30T07:02Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum f3a9644139eac17acbb91bfce7f68e2
This command was run using /home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.0.0-alpha1.jar
```

after install Hive 2.1.1

```
#Hive environment
export HIVE_HOME=/home/hduser/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/hduser/Hadoop/lib/*:.
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/hduser/hive/lib/*:.
```

hive-env.sh

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/hduser/hadoop
```

and db-derby-10.13.1.1.

```
#Derby environment
export DERBY_HOME=/home/hduser/derby
export PATH=$PATH:$DERBY_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$DERBY_HOME/lib/derby.jar:$DERBY_HOME/lib/derbytools.jar
```

Config Metastore hive-site.xml

```
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true </value>
    <description>
jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true
      JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore.
      To use SSL to encrypt/authenticate the connection, provide database-specific SSL flag in the connection URL.
      For example, jdbc:postgresql://myhost/db?ssl=true for postgres database.
    </description>
  </property>
```

then try to run HIVE, have error

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hduser/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/hduser/hive/lib/hive-common-2.1.1.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:366)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:558)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1654)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3367)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3406)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3386)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3640)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1652)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 3.0.0-alpha1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getMajorVersion(ShimLoader.java:169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.loadShims(ShimLoader.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getHadoopShims(ShimLoader.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getDataSourceProps(ObjectStore.java:476)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:278)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:599)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:564)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:626)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:238)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70)
        ... 28 more
```

What version of Hive (Derby) will work with Hadoop 3.0.0? How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicate slf4j logging jar, you can remove this lib:

```
rm -r -f /home/hduser/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar
```

Comment: Thank you for variant, BUT after remove lib HIVE return error "
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/hduser/hive/lib/hive-common-2.1.1.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 3.0.0-alpha1
"

Comment: Ok, can you try this: locate log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar and you must delete the library that you don't need

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the errors in the log, detail is as below:

If you check the corresponding source file. The location path is  `$HIVE_SRC_HOME\shims\common\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\hive\shims\ShimLoader.java`, you will find that it is **compatibility problem (focus on the comment of the code)**.

```
/**
 * Return the "major" version of Hadoop currently on the classpath.
 * Releases in the 1.x and 2.x series are mapped to the appropriate
 * 0.x release series, e.g. 1.x is mapped to "0.20S" and 2.x
 * is mapped to "0.23".
 */
public static String getMajorVersion() {
  String vers = VersionInfo.getVersion();

  String[] parts = vers.split("\\.");
  if (parts.length < 2) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Illegal Hadoop Version: " + vers +
        " (expected A.B.* format)");
  }

  switch (Integer.parseInt(parts[0])) {
  case 2:
    return HADOOP23VERSIONNAME;
  default:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: " + vers);
  }
}
```

So the answer is that maybe U will **downgrade Hadoop version**.
If you think that you can cheat compile (modify the version) and Hadoop 2.x apparently (Hadoop 3.x actually) adapted well to Hive 2.x, you can have a try.

Noted that you may encounter more uncanny problem.